# How to access data members of a class in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am setting up a model using Process Modeling Library of Anylogic. I have an agent class called "Customer" and it has a boolean variable called "VIP". I have two  sources  which create instances of the type Customer. I want to access the variable "VIP" of each instance created, so I can set it equal to true in the first source, and set it equal to "false" in the second one. How can I access the class field "VIP" of each of these instances in the "source" or later in the "selectOutput" when I am sorting them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it from actions of `Source` block, e.g., inside its On At Exit action:
`agent.VIP = true;`

`agent` is local variable that refers to agent that is leaving `Source` block at the moment. You may learn local variables in [Bank Office tutorial](http://www.anylogic.com/anylogic/help/nav/1_2).

Answer (score 1):

Make a new instance of the class with the data name, for instance:

```
Customer john = new Customer();
Customer jane = new Customer();
```

Inside of your customer class I recommend using getter and setter methods for vip, such as:

```
public static void getVIP()
{
    return VIP;
}

public static void setVIP(boolean choice)
{
    VIP = choice;
}
```

Then just do this for whatever your actual object instance name will be

```
john.setVIP(true);
jane.setVIP(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is the source is creating thousands of instances of this class type and it is done automatically, so you cannot use names for all of them.